# Output doesn't appear on standard output in Python when writing in try... except: block

Tags: python, python-2.7

```
import urllib2
import webbrowser
import time
import sys

URL = "http://nonexisting"

while True:
    try:
        website = urllib2.urlopen(URL, timeout=1)

        if website:
            webbrowser.open_new(URL)
            break

    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        break

    except:
        sys.stdout.write('.')
        time.sleep(1)
```

I expect this code to write out a dot every second, but instead nothing is happening and when I press <kbd>CTRL-C</kbd> I get this output:

```
^C..........Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "stackoverflow_question.py", line 21, in <module>
    time.sleep(1)
KeyboardInterrupt
```

So every dot appear *after* the interrupt. Why is that ? How can I reach the expected result ?
I tried with `print` statement either with the same result. On OS X and linux too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You did not flush the buffer, so the output did not actually happen; it's stored somewhere in limbo.

After you interrupt, the buffer gets flushed.

See these links for more information:

[Disable output buffering](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/107705/python-output-buffering)

[How to flush output of Python print?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/230751/how-to-flush-output-of-python-print?lq=1)

Also, quote from mgilson from the comment:

> this code will spend most of it's time in time.sleep. During that interval, the KeyboardInterrupt won't get caught.

Comment: Also, this code will spend most of it's time in `time.sleep`.  During that interval, the `KeyboardInterrupt` won't get caught.

Comment: indeed ! But the program is interrupted anyway :D So how can I catch it and handle it properly ?

Comment: @Walkman: move the while into the try.  For a fuller answer, ask a new question.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try using print istead of sys.stdout.write?

```
print '.'
```